# Spring-Boot error:404 error in loading the template

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

in my spring boot application i have the following `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

as controller i have the simple one as below:

```
    @Controller
    public class ThyemeleafController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home() {
            return "home";
        }
    }
```

and then i have a simple `home.html` in the `src/main/resources/templates` which contains `helloWorld`. But when i run the application and go to url:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

it complains with:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Sep 29 17:15:13 GMT-12:00 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Answer (score -1):

I got my answer. I wrote my controller in another package so, i must ask the spring boot to scan that package and make the essential beans from it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.eventer.controller")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need @ComponentScan("com.eventer.controller") with spring boot.

Comment: You must follow Java’s recommended package naming conventions. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html